# Is there a way to mange multiple models in the same table for a ModelAdmin in Silverstripe 4?

Tags: php, model, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Currently, I'm managing multiple models in the same model admin, but they're managed in different tabs of the model admin page. I was wondering if there's a way to combine all the models into the same table since the data is somewhat similar. This would save time for anyone working in the CMS from having to change tabs every time. I also set up filters in the gridfield filter header to make sorting and filtering much easier if I could get this working.

This is what I'm doing so far.

```php
<?php

class ReportsAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{
    private static $url_segment = 'reports';
    private static $menu_title = 'Reports';
    private static $menu_icon_class = 'cms-icon-drawer';
    private static $managed_models = [
        Model1::class,
        Model2::class,
        Model3::class,
        Model4::class,
        Model5::class,
    ];

    public function getEditForm($id = null, $fields = null)
    {
        $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);
        $grid = $form->Fields()->fieldByName($this->sanitiseClassName($this->modelClass));
        $list = $grid->getList();
        $grid->setList($list);
        $grid->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType(GridFieldAddNewButton::class);
        $grid->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType(GridFieldImportButton::class);
        $grid->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton());

        return $form;
    }
}
```

I want it to be something like this, all in one page.

```
  Col 1   | Col 2 | Col 3
  Model 1 | Data  | Data  
  Model 4 | Data  | Data  
  Model 2 | Data  | Data  
  Model 3 | Data  | Data
  Model 5 | Data  | Data
```

php 7.3, Silverstripe 4.3.1

Comment: If they have a common parent class, you can add that parent class to the managed models list

Comment: @RobbieAverill I see. I didn't think of it that way. Currently, they don't have a common parent class (except DataObject). But I can easily rewrite the models to be children of a common parent class. Thank You!